# URL Routing / rewriting in asp.net webform using c# for framework 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms

I am working on a website which is almost complete. Website has been developed in ASP.Net, C# Framework 4.0.

I want to add a functionality for URL Routing  / rewriting to make my URL more user friendly. I have found plenty of example on net but most of the examples are like http://www.example.com/phone or http://www.example.com/computer.

In my case my page is dependent on multiple query string like PageID, Language, ArticleID.

How can i convert below example URL to one as shown below

http://webd:8080/ArticleDetails.aspx?Language=en-US&PageID=19&ArticleID=18
Should be
http://webd:8080/Article/Article-title-should-appear-here.aspx

http://webd:8080/Archive.aspx?PageId=7&Language=en-US
Should be
http://webd:8080/Archive

http://webd:8080/Archive.aspx?PageId=7&Language=en-USx
Should be
[http://webd:8080/الذاتية/وسوف-تذهب-المادة-الرابعة-العنوان-هنا.aspx](http://webd:8080/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%A9/%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%81-%D8%AA%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%87%D9%86%D8%A7.aspx)

Yes, This is a multilingual website right now with English and Arabic version and later we need to add Spanish and the other languages also.

I have seen few examples on the net but i want some one to point me to a complete example and if it possible to have same for Arabic version of the website also.

I should be somehow able to pass Language=en-US PageID=19 ArticleID=18 and create the user friend url. I would appreciate a complete example for me to have a kick start.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used an open-source URL rewriting component called [UrlRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/), which should help you create the URL's you require.

But I have not tested this component to show Arabic.

These posts should help you in getting started if you plan on using UrlRewriter:
http://www.blogiversity.org/blogs/blogdayafternoon/archive/2008/12/18/url-rewriting-using-intelligencia-urlrewriter.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is handling the Application_BeginRequest route for rewriting the url.
Add a Global.asax to your project (Global Application Class) - there are some predefined methods in that class. Use the Application_BeginRequest to rewrite your url with Context.RewritePath.

For instance based upon a datatable:

```
            DataTable paths = BusinessLogic.Article.Path_List();
            for (int i = 0; i < paths.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (String.Compare(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString(), paths.Rows[i]["ART_Path"].ToString(), true) == 0)
                {
                    BusinessLogic.ArticleTypes aType = (BusinessLogic.ArticleTypes)Convert.ToInt32(paths.Rows[i]["ART_Type"]);
                    Context.RewritePath("/article.aspx?type=" + aType.ToString() + "&id=" + paths.Rows[i]["ART_ID"].ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Example for question:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Request.Url.AbsolutePath returns your path with preceding / -- example /default.aspx


    // you do not want to hardcode this, but read it from a config file or database, but for the example it'll suffice
    Dictionary<string,string> urls = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    urls.Add("/Article/Article-title-should-appear-here", "/ArticleDetails.aspx?Language=en-US&PageID=19&ArticleID=18");
    urls.Add("/Archive", "/Archive.aspx?PageId=7&Language=en-US");
    urls.Add("/الذاتية/وسوف-تذهب-المادة-الرابعة-العنوان-هنا", "/Archive.aspx?PageId=7&Language=en-USx");
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in urls)
    {
        if (String.Compare(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, kvp.Key, true) == 0 || String.Compare(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, kvp.Key + ".aspx", true) == 0)
        {
            Context.RewritePath(kvp.Value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will if you can give a complete example or point me a working example with source code, I dont have much experience in c# and have to do URL rewrite for 1st time. What you have show in logical but i am not able to understand it. I appreciate your effort. Thanks

Comment: see the new example as attached above.